# how do I use openPGP.js library with angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, openpgp

I'm pretty new to Angular. I'm trying to incorporate the openPGP library to my app (client side). I need some help on how to incorporate a javascript library to the Angular App. Thanks!

I'm reading through the openPGP docs https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs
and the example provide in the docs is below:

```
var openpgp = require('openpgp');
var key = '-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK ... END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----';
var publicKey = openpgp.key.readArmored(key);
var pgpMessage = openpgp.encryptMessage(publicKey.keys, 'Hello, World!');
```

I prefer not to use require to source in openPGP to my app. So I've tried 
`var openpgp = window.openpgp;` which seems to not throw any error here. However, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined` error.

I should mention that I have installed openpgp using bower install.

I'm still trying to figure out what I can do to refer to openPGP in the Angular app. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to know, that StackOverflow Netiquette ( published as a recommended reading ) is not much tolerant to extremely broad questions. Some moderators even execute a [close] or [freeze] on such cases. **Try to narrow down the issue you have tried to solve, might be posta a <_code-snippet_> and mention what other things you have already tested, right?**

Comment: added more context to my question. thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on the client-side, use a script tag, like

```
<script src="/path/to/openpgp.js"></script>
```

instead of `require()`